# Use structural equation modeling to build a composite score / index

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am thinking of using SEM - specifically with MIMIC model on a household survey to build a multidimensional score/index that will bring together both formative and reflective indicators.

The idea is to classify each respondent from the survey according to the resulting score. I am looking at the same approach than the one used by the [FAO Resilience Index Measurement and Analysis](http://www.fao.org/3/a-i5665e.pdf)

I am missing one step. Once, I have performed satisfactory Confirmatory Factor Analysis, how can I extract such  formula and apply it for each of the observation from my dataset?

Thanks!

PS: I have looked most at [lavaan](http://lavaan.ugent.be) package.

Comment: Based on additional research, I understand that a potential way forward would be to:

Comment: Based on additional research, I understand that a potential way forward would be to use 2 approaches to Structural Equation Modeling together: 

1. perform first  "__Covariance Structure Analysis__" in order to identify the best model structure - This would then include the Confirmatory Factor Analysis

2. use complementary "__Partial Least Squares Path Modeling__" (PLS-PM) to actionate the model using the built-in scoring functions as described [here](http://www.gastonsanchez.com/PLS_Path_Modeling_with_R.pdf#page=43)

Comment: happy to get more ideas though !

Comment: PLS is never good for anything http://public.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/faculty/edwardsj/McIntoshetal2014.pdf and http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428112474693. Check lavaan Google group for more specific software and syntax support.